# is_default radio button symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, checkbox, radio-button, symfony-1.4

I have the follow:

```
abstract class BaseSellerForm extends BaseFormDoctrine
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'id'         => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'name'       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'commission' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'active'     => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
      'is_default' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
    ));
```

`is_default` should be a radio button, because only one field must be checked, but I don't know how to change it to radio button, was searching about `sfWidgetFormSelectRadio` without succcess.

Comment: Where are values coming from? Doctrine? or you have them defined?

Answer (score 0):

did you try under [sfWidgetFormChoice](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfWidgetFormChoice)?

Comment: how? the problem i see is that i don't have the values to pass to formChoice yet. How could you make this happen?

Comment: What do you mean "i don't have the values to pass to formChoice yet" Where are values coming from? Doctrine? or you have them defined?

Comment: The values come from a table, but are shown as you can see here: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/3496/sellers.jpg
What i wanna change is "Predeterminado" (translating: default) to be a radio button or just let you select one field. Thanks!